# Copying database from Asset Folder crashes in some android devices

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have trouble copying database from Asset folder to database folder. I use this code:

```
public class DBVocab extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH= "data/data/APP_NAME/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "wocab";
    private SQLiteDatabase dbObj;
    private Context context;

    public DBVocab(Context context) {
        super(context,  DB_NAME, null, 3);
        this. context  = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void createDB() throws IOException {

        this.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.i("Readable ends....................","end");

        try {
            copyDB();
            Log.i("copy db ends....................","end");

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }

    String dialogText = "Copying Database";

    private Runnable changeMessage = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Log.v(TAG, strCharacters);
            Main.pDialog.setMessage(dialogText);
        }
    };

    private void showLoading(){

    }

    public boolean checkDB(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        ProgressDialog pD = Main.pDialog;

        try{
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            Log.i("myPath ......",path);
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            Log.i("myPath ......",path);
            if (checkDB!=null)
            {
                CardsBackup cards = new CardsBackup();
                Cursor c= checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM wocab", null);
                //Log.i("Cursor.......",c.getString(0));
                c.moveToFirst();
                String contents[]=new String[100];
                int flag=0;
                while(! c.isAfterLast())
                {
                    String temp="";
                    int s1=c.getInt(0);
                    pD.setProgress(s1);
                    String word=c.getString(1);
                    String phonetic=c.getString(2);
                    String type=c.getString(3);
                    String mean=c.getString(4);
                    String sample=c.getString(5);
                    String sample_mean=c.getString(6);
                    String grade=c.getString(7);
                    if(flag<contents.length) contents[flag]=temp;
                    flag=flag+1;
                    Log.i("DB values.........",temp);
                    try{
                        cards.add(context,word,phonetic,type,mean,sample,sample_mean,grade);
                    } catch (SQLException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("Add to Database ......... ","failure to ADD");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "failure to add!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
                c.moveToFirst();
                while(! c.isAfterLast()){
                    String temp="";
                    int s1=c.getInt(0)+2911;
                    pD.setProgress(s1);
                    if(s1 >= 825+2911) break;
                    String word=c.getString(1);
                    String phonetic=c.getString(2);
                    String type=c.getString(3);
                    String mean=c.getString(4);
                    String sample=c.getString(5);
                    String sample_mean=c.getString(6);
                    String grade="7";
                    if(flag<contents.length) contents[flag]=temp;
                    flag=flag+1
                    try{
                        cards.add(context,word,phonetic,type,mean,sample,sample_mean,grade);
                    } catch (SQLException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "failure to add!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
                Log.i("DB count.........", ""+flag);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    public void copyDB() throws IOException{
        try {
            Log.i("inside copyDB....................","start");

            InputStream ip =  context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME+".db");
            Log.i("Input Stream....",ip+"");
            String op=  DB_PATH  +  DB_NAME ;
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( op);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = ip.read(buffer))>0){
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                //Log.i("Content.... ",length+"");
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            ip.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("error", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void openDB() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        dbObj = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        Log.e("db","open DB......"+dbObj.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(dbObj != null)
            dbObj.close();

        super.close();
    }
}
```

It works in my device.
But in some android devices it crashes in the middle of the copying database.
The database in the assets folder has 2911 words and i recopy the 800 first words.

Can Somebody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you declared runtime permission ?

Comment: What is the error in the logcat when it crashes?

Comment: Stack-trace please.

Comment: DB_PATH= "data/data/APP_NAME/databases/"; That should be DB_PATH= "/data/data/APP_NAME/databases/"; And under modern Android versions that path does not even exist. You should use getFilesDir() instead. Or yet better getDatabasePath().

Comment: What kind of permission? Where are you talking about? You dont need permissions for this.

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 it works in my devices, but doesn't work in some users divices

Comment: I have no permissions declared in manifest

Comment: @greenapps it is correct path in the project.

Comment: What do you mean? That path does not even exist on many devices!

Comment: @greenapps but it crash in the middle of the progress (when progress is 30 40 ...%) and it crashes in the new version that i recopy 800 first words at last. which added in last version

Comment: `throw new Error("Error copying database");`. You have a catch of an IOExeption there. But you are not examining (with e.getMessge() for example) which IOExeption. So the user does not see it. And so cant tell you. Lost chance.

Comment: `and it crashes in the new version` ??? What new version? What do you mean?

Comment: So you cannot produce a LogCat? Why not? Post it if you have.

Comment: `The database in the assets folder has 2911 words and i recopy the 800 first words.`. Why only 800? And what do you mean with 'recopy' ? It looks as if you did not tell the whole story.

Comment: `it crashes in the middle of the copying database. `. So in the middle somewhere in function 'copyDB()'? This function is only called once. Only whenn you install your app. It looks a wrong place to me calling it in onCreate.

Comment: Throw away that code and just use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Comment: @greenapps I add all rows of asset database to my database but i add 800 first words two times with different id.

Comment: `copying database from Asset folder to database folder.`. That is done by the function `copyDB()`. I already asked you if that function gave the errors but you do not answer. You only need function copyDB to copy your database from asssets to that folder. Thats all. For what you use the rest of the code i dont know and you did not tell. So you can do away with  SQLiteAssetHelper and only use function copyDB().